# reset radio Button choice on destroy in android application

Tags: android, radio-button

my application has two radio buttons. They needs to turn on/off the Wi-Fi.when I close the application the radio buttons stay clicked and when open the application again I find the choice I got before.this for me it's a problem..for example I turn off the Wi-Fi via application,I go out in my homescreen and I turn it on by a widget or in the settings..when I open my application again I find the radio button "turn Wi-Fi off" clicked.is there a way to "doesn't show"the choice made before close the application?I don't know if you understand me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you clear your choice inside `onResume()` of your activity. As I remember you can do that using `setSelected()` method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#setSelected(boolean)